# the react native close app when the size app 1 GB - PDF react native

Tags: android-studio, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a problem that I will explain and want to solve
I have an app you've built with (React native)
There is a company that has a large number of files in the file you want to apply without Internet
Out of line, its data size reaches approximately 10 GB
When adding only two sections of this data to the application, the size of this data reached 1 GB
I have a problem, that is, an application on android in Fremorek (react native cli)

It no longer works because of the large size of the application and if you delete multiple files and make it less than 1 GB, the application will work normally and smoothly
Terms of work on the application
All data is offline
The application works without the Internet
The application is not uploaded to the store
When the application is finished I install it on 100 iPads

I want to solve this problem that the application suffers